# How to improve running asynchronous task

Tags: java, spring, task

I have task which run every 1 minute. This task contains couple of method which process some data. Process1 read data(one or more) in status 1 and in the end of this process update status to 2. Process2 read data in status 2  and so on. So now I want to improve this processing using `taskExecutor` (`org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`) to run it parallel:

```
public void process1() {

    List<Object> objects = someDao.readDataWithStatus("1");
    if (objects == null || objects.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    for (final Object object : objects) {
            if (BooleanUtils.isTrue(isParalelProcess())) {
                taskExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        process(object);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                process(object);
            }           
    }
}
```

Lets say we have one object with status1 and we want parallel processing. Task which runs every one minute start processing. Process1 read data with status 1 put it in taskExecutor and go to the next method. This method didnt find object which status 2 so there is nothing to do here. After one minute process2 read object with status 2 and so on. Processing object takes from 1s to couple of minute. As you can see there is significant slowdown in process which takes just couple of second. Is there option how to improve this processing ?

Comment: do you mean to run task 2 just after task 1 is completed ?

Comment: there is just one task.

Comment: so actually i dont understand the problem

Comment: problem is when process1/2.. (in my task) takes just couple of second then parallel processing is significant slowdown then no parallel. And I want to improve it. Question is how

Comment: maybe you can do some preprocessing of data and based on size then decide if is it worth to do it parallel ?

Comment: parallel processing is just variable which can be change thought jmx but not in app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent little time on it. It may helpful to you.

```
public class SampleTest
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int noOfThreads = 100;
        int maxThreadinQue = 100;

        LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> processOneworkQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();

        ThreadPoolExecutor processOneThreadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(noOfThreads, noOfThreads, 0L,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,

                processOneworkQueue, new ThreadFactory()
                {
                    private AtomicInteger itsCounter = new AtomicInteger();

                    public Thread newThread(Runnable theRunnable)
                    {
                        Thread aThread = new Thread(theRunnable, "theThreadName" + "#" + itsCounter.getAndIncrement());
                        aThread.setDaemon(true);
                        return aThread;
                    }
                });

        LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> processTwoworkQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();

        ThreadPoolExecutor processTwoThreadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(noOfThreads, noOfThreads, 0L,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,

                processTwoworkQueue, new ThreadFactory()
                {
                    private AtomicInteger itsCounter = new AtomicInteger();

                    public Thread newThread(Runnable theRunnable)
                    {
                        Thread aThread = new Thread(theRunnable, "theThreadName" + "#" + itsCounter.getAndIncrement());
                        aThread.setDaemon(true);
                        return aThread;
                    }
                });

        ArrayList<SampleObject> sampleObjects = new ArrayList<SampleObject>();
        sampleObjects.add(new SampleObject());
        sampleObjects.add(new SampleObject());
        sampleObjects.add(new SampleObject());
        sampleObjects.add(new SampleObject());
        sampleObjects.add(new SampleObject());
        sampleObjects.add(new SampleObject());
        sampleObjects.add(new SampleObject());
        sampleObjects.add(new SampleObject());
        sampleObjects.add(new SampleObject());
        sampleObjects.add(new SampleObject());
        sampleObjects.add(new SampleObject());
        sampleObjects.add(new SampleObject());
        sampleObjects.add(new SampleObject());
        sampleObjects.add(new SampleObject());

        while (true)
        {
            Iterator<SampleObject> it = sampleObjects.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext())
            {

                final SampleObject sampleObject = it.next();

                if (sampleObject.getStatus() == 0)
                {
                    if (processOneworkQueue.size() < maxThreadinQue)
                    {
                        processOneThreadPoolExecutor.submit(new Runnable()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void run()
                            {
                                process1(sampleObject);

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                else if (sampleObject.getStatus() == 1)
                {
                    if (processTwoworkQueue.size() < maxThreadinQue)
                    {
                        processTwoThreadPoolExecutor.submit(new Runnable()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void run()
                            {
                                process2(sampleObject);

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                else if (sampleObject.getStatus() == 2)
                {

                    it.remove();

                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void process1(SampleObject sampleObject)
    {
        System.out.println("process1");
        sampleObject.setStatus(1);

    }

    static void process2(SampleObject sampleObject)
    {
        System.out.println("process2");
        sampleObject.setStatus(2);
    }

}

class SampleObject
{
    int status=0;

    public int getStatus()
    {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status)
    {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```